# Is the source code placed in the App_Code special folder in an ASP.NET Web Forms application as reliable as a compiled app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I'm maintaining a legacy application that was written in Web Forms, and we have started bolting new functionality on to it that makes heavy use of API's.  It's also written in VB .NET.

I've worked out that I can install the WebAPI nuget packages and set up routing in the Global.asax file.  I've also worked out that I can put .cs files in the App_code directory and set up controllers etc (as I am far more productive with C#).

Does using the app_code directory make for a reliable application? I've read online that stuff in the App_Code directory gets compiled at runtime, so what does this? The installed version of .NET on the hosting server?

I recognise that mixing C# and VB Net in the same project, as well as Web Forms and Web API in the same project will make for a maintenance nightmare.  I'm just using Web API because there is no equivalent Web Forms method that will let me produce API responses apart from using Web Handlers which are huge to write.

Comment: _good idea architecturally_ is opinion based; when you say _safe_, do you mean _secure, inaccessible directly by the client?_ then yes, it's safe. Here's more info on [ASP.NET Special Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ex526337(v=vs.140))

Comment: I mean, I've read online that the code in that folder gets compiled when first accessed by the client....... so I assume that it gets compiled by the installed version of .NET on the hosting server?  I mean safe, as in, as reliable as compiling and hosting a project, as opposed to having app_code things that get compiled at runtime, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question - I understood it differently (in fact, I suggested an edit based on my understanding of what you asked)

Comment: You can [precompile your App_Code code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs)

Comment: @CoolBots thats pretty much exactly what I was looking for.  Post it as an answer if you want some of those sweet, sweet internet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in that sense it's reliable; you can also [precompile your App_Code code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs)

Comment: Thanks heaps.  No more VB NET code in my controllers!